# Does it have any value getting a PhD in engineering after 45?

Tags: career-switch

I am talking about academia and research.

Suppose, a person doesn't have either professional or academic credentials or experiences. Suddenly he decides to study engineering because he wants to change his stagnation both financially and socially. So, he enrolls in BSc in an engineering program at the age of 40. He completes his BSc at the age of 44, completes his MSc at the age of 45-47, and then completes his Ph.D. in engineering at the age of 49-55.

- Does this Ph.D. degree have any material value for this person?

There are multiple factors to think about.

Firstly, this person never had any corporate and academia related job experience. It is hard to believe that he would be able to get along with these work environments. It is generally hard to mould someone's brain and personality at the age of 40+. So, I believe that he will find hard-times finding a job.

Secondly, most people are forced to retire at the age of 65-68. If he starts his job at 49-55, he has only 16-13 years of his life left for earning money. The amount he earns with his Ph.D. is highly unlikely to compensate for the earnings he sacrificed while getting his degrees.

So, my view would be: this person is not gaining much with his Ph.D.

What do you think?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the job sought. If the PhD topic was directly industrially useful to an employer and filled a skills gap for them, it may increase that person's value, but so far as academic credentials serve as generic "peacocks' tails" in the jobs market, it's unlikely to add much extra value in your mid-50s when your age and work experience can usually already speak equivalently for your general intellectual qualities (increasing the baseline wage available to you without a PhD), and when employers can no longer sensibly consider your long-term potential.

Comment: If this person is you, there's no need to speculate about experience, personality and so on. If this person is not you, it's none of your business whether they are wise or unwise to take a degree for whatever reason they may choose to. And either way, "is it good to take this course?" questions are off topic here. Sorry.

Comment: "Suppose, a person doesn't have either professional or academic credentials or experiences." So that person had no job whatsoever? Not even a minimum wage job? I find that hard to believe. Who is paying the bills for that person? Also, engineering in what? There are many different types of engineering degrees. They're not all equal.

Comment: It's arguable whether a PhD has a material value for those who obtain that degree in their 20s or 30s or 40s, let alone their 50s or 60s. Material gain is not the reason to chase after a PhD.  The material payoff tends to be small, or even negative. Unless one insists on getting a job at a PhD-happy organization, the same kinds of roles that PhDs fulfill in industry are typically available to those with a masters degree, and sometimes even with "just" a bachelors degree. People go after a PhD for a love of learning, a need to solve a previously unsolved problem.

Comment: @DavidHammen, you have probably missed the 1st line of the question.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, taxi driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Material value is not the only reason to do things. The pursuit of a PhD might provide "material" value in the form of quality of life. It could open up job opportunities that could provide a higher degree of work-life balance, traveling opportunities, better location. The PhD might open up specific career paths that might offer more industry influence, higher visibility or prestige.

Materially speaking, it's possible that this person is looking at the opportunities along the path that MIGHT make it materially worthwhile. Someone who goes from making 80-100k/year that lands a job at 200k+ because of a PhD absolutely makes up for it over that time. The new career path might open up new investment opportunities in the form of contacts, jobs with stock options, and esoteric knowledge of the industry.

As for the "you can't teach an old dog new tricks" angle, anyone willing to take this kind of leap to improve their circumstances should be given the benefit of the doubt with respect to adapting to new environments and situations. Completing the degree programs you mention in the time frame you mention is an absolute commitment to be respected.